# How can I even use the'else' syntax in Python?

Tags: python, json, for-loop, if-statement, grammar

I am reading data from a JSON file to check the existence of some values.

In the JSON structure below, I try to find `adomain` from the data in `bid` and check if there is a `cat` value, which is not always present.

How do I fix it in the syntax below?

```py
import pandas as pd
import json
    
path = 'C:/MyWorks/Python/Anal/data_sample.json'
    
records = [json.loads(line) for line in open(path, encoding='utf-8')]
    
adomain = [
    rec['win_res']['seatbid'][0]['bid'][0]['adomain']
    for rec in records
    if 'adomain' in rec
]
```

Here is a data sample:

```json
[
  { "win_res": {
    "id": "12345",
    "seatbid": [
      {
        "bid": [
          {
            "id": "12345",
            "impid": "1",
            "price": 0.1,
            "adm": "",
            "adomain": [
              "adomain.com"
            ],
            "iurl": "url.com",
            "cid": "11",
            "crid": "11",
            "cat": [
              "IAB12345"
            ],
            "w": 1,
            "h": 1
          }
        ],
        "seat": "1"
      }
    ]
  }}
]
```

As a result, the `adomain` value exists unconditionally, but the `cat` value may not be present sometimes.

So, if `cat` exists in `adomain`, I want to express `adomain` and `cat` in this way, but if there is no `adomain`, the `cat` value, how can I do it?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking here.

Comment: have you used a debugger to see what your intermediate data is

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear but I think this is what you are looking for:

```py
import json
    
path = 'C:/MyWorks/Python/Anal/data_sample.json'
    
with open(path, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    records = json.load(f)

    adomain = [
        _['win_res']['seatbid'][0]['bid'][0]['adomain']
        for _ in records
        if _['win_res']['seatbid'][0]['bid'][0].get('adomain', None) and
           _['win_res']['seatbid'][0]['bid'][0].get('cat', None)
    ]
```

The code above will add the value of `['win_res']['seatbid'][0]['bid'][0]['adomain']` to the list `adomain` only if there is a `['win_res']['seatbid'][0]['bid'][0]['cat']` corresponding value.

The code will be a lot clearer if we just walk through a `bids` list. Something like this:

```py
import json
    
path = 'C:/MyWorks/Python/Anal/data_sample.json'
    
with open(path, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    records = json.load(f)

    bids = [_['win_res']['seatbid'][0]['bid'][0] for _ in records]

    adomain = [
        _['adomain']
        for _ in bids
        if _.get('adomain', None) and _.get('cat', None)
    ]
```